# Dashboard like user interface to display content in a specific part

Tags: jquery, html, css, dashboard

I want to make HTML dashboard but the problem is that how can I make the pages to display in the specific area in dashboard without changing the entire page. I want to navigate user to another page but there shouldn't be any change in the sidebar section.

Comment: ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can't navigate to another page and keep parts of the previous page loaded. You *can* use Ajax to load new content and then display it within a specified element in the current page (replacing the old content of that element), a style of navigation known as a "single page app" (SPA). (Or you can use an iframe for the content and have it navigate to another page, but I wouldn't recommend that.)

Comment: Thanx for the AJAX idea I literally forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices, if you have a backend with a database you'd typically use AJAX to dynamically generate content on a page without reloading the page.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

What could be considered an easier method, would be to use iframes. These are essentially frames or windows to other web pages embedded within your own web page.
https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

and instead of **AJAX** or **iframe** I can simply use JQuery's **load** method to load the html content